# REST Api Access denied for build service account

Tags: tfs-2015

I am using the REST API to gain information about build definitions. Running the powershell script locally no problem, however when running under our build service account I get:

> ***Invoke-RestMethod : {"$id":"1","innerException":null,"message":"Access Denied:
>   svc-live-tfsbuild needs the following  permission(s) to perform this
>   action: Edit instance-level 
>   information","typeName":"Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Server.AccessCheckException,
>   Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Server, Version=14.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, 
>   PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a","typeKey":"AccessCheckException","errorCode":0,"eventId":3000}
>   At E:\Build\A001\67afc80c\DevTools\TfsApiFunctions.ps1:269 char:24
>   + $ApiJson = Invoke-RestMethod -UseDefaultCredentials -Uri $Uri;

What access rights does an account need to call the Rest-API?

Comment: The message suggests `Edit instance-level information` is required.  Out of interest, are these build definitions XAML or vNext types?

Answer (score 0):

Add the designated service account via Tfs Administration Console, there you can assign specific rights like Edit instance level. Doh!